# Jenkins and powershell. Download file

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a script in Powershell and want to run this on many servers.

It's running from Jenkins via a Powershell step, the input param $env:servers

Simple example:

```
$SrvPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$($ENV:SlavePassword)" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$ENV:SlaveUser", $SrvPassword)

Invoke-Command -Computername $env:servers -ScriptBlock {
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("\\server1.domain.ru\123\123.zip","C:\123.zip")
}  -Credential $cred
```

But when I build it with parametrs, i got error:

```
[firstDeploy] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins6658148949844825772.ps1'"
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path '\\server1.domain.ru\123\123.zip' is denied."
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
    + PSComputerName        : server2.domain.ru
```

When i do this without jenkins all work fine. Share full access. What's wrong?

Comment: is your jenkins running as system? if you dont know check services or do `whoami` in the build job. if it is - it wont work, you need to use `network service` or windows\domain account and grant that account permissions to the share (ntfs + share level)

Comment: when use network service slave is down, when use windows\domain account don't work.